# Admin trying to add Field History Tracking to Quote Line Items, Insufficient Privileges?

Tags: history-tracking, quotelineitem, insufficient-privileges

Got a weird situation going on. I see that I can set "Field History Tracking" in my Quote Line Items, but I'm getting an unusual error:

[image: Error Message]

I'm not sure what solution is as I have a standard admin profile, and we have modify all on Quotes. Been reading up on this article: [Insufficient Privileges Errors](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=admin_insufficient_privileges_flowchart.htm&type=5) but it's not clear on how to resolve the issue since our sharing model is pretty loose.

If you can help out with this, that would be great as we would like to see what price changes our employees are making to line-items. Thank you.

Comment: Did you Enable Field Tracking History on the object itself?

Comment: I guess I assumed that since the button was there, that it was already on. Checking now.

Comment: @sfdcfox where would you enable this? documentation says to just click "Set History Tracking" which is what I'm currently doing and is producing the above error. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&type=5

Comment: I think thinker means user can not Set History Tracking for "Quote Line Items" with the System Administrator profile, so weird. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8nyP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8nyP.png)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can't yet track field history on quotes (and presumably quote line items). Only the standard objects in the documentation you've looked at support this feature. See [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E7tTQAS).

Comment: Ok, good to know. Seems odd that they would have the ability to enable this feature and that the error message would be permissions related. Maybe we should create an idea to change the error message for adding quote line item history tracking :D